# how to change textview size into all devices in android

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator

hi i am doing one app in android  for all sizes of mobiles and tablets.imageviews displyed in all sizes good.but i facing problm in textview font size.in my app i need to display textview with that background and text,but different sizes text size is displaying not correctly.any one having idea pls help me. i tried using below code...

**MainActivity .class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
 RelativeLayout alpha_page2;
 ImageView alpha_back,alpha_back1;
 TextView option121;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
     Log.i("screenHeight",""+screenHeight);
     Log.i("screenWidth",""+screenWidth);
     Log.i("screendensity",""+screendensity);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int letpading=(int)(116*(screenWidth/1024));
    int toppading=(int)(79*(screenHeight/600));

    int textsiz=(int)(50*(screendensity/600));
    option121 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    option121.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog_b_blank);
    option121.setText("A");
    option121.setText(Color.BLACK);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutoption121 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) option121.getLayoutParams();       
    layoutoption121.height=(int)(180*(screenHeight/600));  
    layoutoption121.width=(int)(180*(screenWidth/1024));
    layoutoption121.topMargin=(int)(100*(screenHeight/600));
    layoutoption121.leftMargin= (int)(250*(screenWidth/1024));
    option121.setPadding(letpading, toppading, 0, 0);

    option121.setTextSize(textsiz);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the way do it. Android takes care of text size for you, use 'sp' (scale-independent pixel) units when specifying text sizes and if you need to configure different sizes for different screens have a read of this:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Basically, you need to define your text sizes in .xml files in the appropriate resource directory:

res/values-large
res/values-xlarge
etc..

Then refer to those constants in your layout xml or your code.

Comment: thanku.but if i ll do like this means in all sizes working well i am facing prblm in text size.in xml i ll give  android:textSize="50sp" means one size its working well.for another sizes its not working

Comment: Read the link. It sounds like you want to specify different text sizes for different screen sizes, is that right? The link describes how to do that.

Comment: i treid like this also but i did get u.u have any other soltution can u tel me

Comment: Trust me, and that's the way to do it. Please post what you tried if you want more help.

Comment: You should not be trying to calculate text size based on the sceensize at runtime. It is unnescessary and very ugly. You need to read and understand the link I gave. Define your text size in screen size specific .xml files and use those constants in your code or xml layouts. Android will automatically pick the correct resource file for your screen size.